Is it not adhesive better name for the tag rather then glue?
It might be more personal but adhesive sound like a better tag to me than glue. Also, the adhesive word is quite popularly used here. 
If not tag rename then at-least adhesive can be a synonym.

It really depends. Different adhesives have different properties and hence uses. You wouldn't use tape for something that hot glue is a better fit for. To that end, [adhesive] might actually be ambiguous.

I will call broader not ambiguous @LegoSonicBoy

This definition I found explaining the difference seems quite helpful.

What Is Glue?
Glue is a substance that allows two surfaces to be bonded together.
  The term is commonly used interchangeably with “adhesive”. Glues are
  often marketed for specific applications—wood glue, thread lock,
  etc.—rather than being marketed based on their chemical compositions,
  such as polyurethane or epoxy.
What Is Adhesive?
An adhesive holds materials together. There are many different types,
  but the different types all describe essentially the same thing.
  Cement, glue and other terms all refer to adhesives of one sort or
  another.

There are 18 glue questions, 12 of them use 'Glue' in the title, most of the others refer to glue in the posts as well. I think the word glue is more commonly understood and used in the context of LEGO constructions.
I have added adhesive as a synonym of glue.
